# What is the difference of Installing Packages via Terminal and via RStudio?

Tags: r, runtime-error, rstudio, bioinformatics, install.packages

**Background**
I am trying to install the package "zip" in terminal of macOS via the command install.packages() after entering 'R':

```html
R
install.packages("zip")
```

I also entered the same command to install the same package in Rstudio console, no problems arise at all (meaning that the functions that come with the package are functional (only in Rstudio)).

**Problem**
Simply put, the package "zip" is not installed. The following error messages (which is extremely long), arise in the terminal:

```html
* installing *source* package ‘zip’ ...
** package ‘zip’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -I/Users/hephaeschuen/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda/- -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  miniz.c zip.c tools/cmdzip.c -o tools/cmdzip
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x2D 0x2D 0x2D 0x20 0x21 0x74 0x61 0x70 0x69 0x2D 0x74 0x62 0x64 0x2D 0x76 0x33 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___assert_rtn", referenced from:
      _tdefl_compress in miniz-444461.o
      _tinfl_decompress in miniz-444461.o
      _tdefl_flush_block in miniz-444461.o
      _tdefl_compress_buffer in miniz-444461.o
      _tdefl_compress_mem_to_output in miniz-444461.o
      _tdefl_write_image_to_png_file_in_memory_ex in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_reader_read_central_dir in miniz-444461.o
      ...
  "___bzero", referenced from:
      _tdefl_init in miniz-444461.o
      _tdefl_compress in miniz-444461.o
      _tinfl_decompress in miniz-444461.o
      _tdefl_flush_block in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_reader_init in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_reader_init_mem in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_reader_init_file_v2 in miniz-444461.o
      ...
  "___error", referenced from:
      _zip_error in zip-fff898.o
      _zip_mkdirp in zip-fff898.o
      _zip_unzip in zip-fff898.o
  "___memcpy_chk", referenced from:
      _tdefl_compress_block in miniz-444461.o
  "___memset_chk", referenced from:
      _mz_zip_writer_add_mem_ex_v2 in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_writer_add_cfile in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_writer_add_from_zip_reader in miniz-444461.o
  "___stack_chk_fail", referenced from:
      _mz_deflate in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_compress2 in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_inflate in miniz-444461.o
      _tinfl_decompress in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_uncompress in miniz-444461.o
      _tdefl_compress_buffer in miniz-444461.o
      _tdefl_compress_mem_to_output in miniz-444461.o
      ...
  "___stack_chk_guard", referenced from:
      _mz_deflate in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_compress2 in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_inflate in miniz-444461.o
      _tinfl_decompress in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_uncompress in miniz-444461.o
      _tdefl_compress_buffer in miniz-444461.o
      _tdefl_compress_mem_to_output in miniz-444461.o
      ...
  "___stderrp", referenced from:
      _cmd_zip_error_handler in cmdzip-d70c7b.o
      _main in cmdzip-d70c7b.o
  "___vsnprintf_chk", referenced from:
      _zip_error in zip-fff898.o
  "_calloc", referenced from:
      _main in cmdzip-d70c7b.o
  "_chmod", referenced from:
      _zip_unzip in zip-fff898.o
  "_exit", referenced from:
      _cmd_zip_error_handler in cmdzip-d70c7b.o
  "_fclose", referenced from:
      _mz_zip_reader_end_internal in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_reader_init_file_v2 in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_reader_extract_to_file in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_writer_end_internal in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_writer_add_file in miniz-444461.o
  "_fflush", referenced from:
      _mz_zip_writer_finalize_archive in miniz-444461.o
  "_fopen", referenced from:
      _mz_zip_reader_init_file_v2 in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_reader_extract_to_file in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_writer_init_file_v2 in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_writer_add_file in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_add_mem_to_archive_file_in_place_v2 in miniz-444461.o
  "_fprintf", referenced from:
      _cmd_zip_error_handler in cmdzip-d70c7b.o
      _main in cmdzip-d70c7b.o
  "_fread", referenced from:
      _mz_zip_file_read_func in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_writer_add_cfile in miniz-444461.o
  "_free", referenced from:
      _mz_free in miniz-444461.o
      _miniz_def_free_func in miniz-444461.o
      _tdefl_compress_mem_to_output in miniz-444461.o
      _tdefl_write_image_to_png_file_in_memory_ex in miniz-444461.o
      _tdefl_compressor_free in miniz-444461.o
      _tinfl_decompress_mem_to_heap in miniz-444461.o
      _tinfl_decompress_mem_to_callback in miniz-444461.o
      ...
     (maybe you meant: _tinfl_decompressor_free, _tdefl_compressor_free , _mz_zip_reader_extract_iter_free , _miniz_def_free_func , _mz_free )
  "_freopen", referenced from:
      _mz_zip_writer_init_from_reader_v2 in miniz-444461.o
  "_fseeko", referenced from:
      _mz_zip_reader_init_file_v2 in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_file_read_func in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_reader_init_cfile in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_file_write_func in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_writer_add_file in miniz-444461.o
  "_ftello", referenced from:
      _mz_zip_reader_init_file_v2 in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_file_read_func in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_reader_init_cfile in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_file_write_func in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_writer_init_cfile in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_writer_add_file in miniz-444461.o
  "_fwrite", referenced from:
      _mz_zip_file_write_callback in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_file_write_func in miniz-444461.o
  "_localtime", referenced from:
      _mz_zip_writer_add_mem_ex_v2 in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_writer_add_cfile in miniz-444461.o
  "_malloc", referenced from:
      _miniz_def_alloc_func in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_compress2 in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_uncompress in miniz-444461.o
      _tdefl_compress_mem_to_output in miniz-444461.o
      _tdefl_write_image_to_png_file_in_memory_ex in miniz-444461.o
      _tdefl_compressor_alloc in miniz-444461.o
      _tinfl_decompress_mem_to_callback in miniz-444461.o
      ...
  "_memcmp", referenced from:
      _mz_zip_reader_locate_file_v2 in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_validate_file in miniz-444461.o
  "_memcpy", referenced from:
      _tdefl_compress in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_inflate in miniz-444461.o
      _tinfl_decompress in miniz-444461.o
      _tdefl_flush_block in miniz-444461.o
      _tdefl_output_buffer_putter in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_mem_read_func in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_reader_extract_iter_read in miniz-444461.o
      ...
  "_memset", referenced from:
      _tinfl_decompress in miniz-444461.o
      _tdefl_compress_block in miniz-444461.o
  "_mkdir", referenced from:
      _zip_mkdirp in zip-fff898.o
      _zip_unzip in zip-fff898.o
     (maybe you meant: _zip_mkdirp)
  "_mktime", referenced from:
      _mz_zip_file_stat_internal in miniz-444461.o
  "_open", referenced from:
      _main in cmdzip-d70c7b.o
  "_read", referenced from:
      _main in cmdzip-d70c7b.o
     (maybe you meant: _mz_zip_reader_get_filename, _mz_zip_writer_init_from_reader , _mz_zip_writer_init_from_reader_v2 , _mz_zip_reader_get_num_files , _mz_zip_reader_extract_to_cfile , _mz_zip_reader_extract_file_iter_new , _mz_zip_reader_extract_iter_new , _mz_zip_reader_extract_file_to_callback , _mz_zip_reader_extract_to_heap , _mz_zip_reader_extract_file_to_mem_no_alloc , _mz_zip_reader_file_stat , _mz_zip_reader_locate_file_v2 , _mz_zip_reader_is_file_a_directory , _mz_zip_reader_extract_file_to_heap , _mz_zip_reader_init_file , _mz_zip_reader_is_file_encrypted , _mz_zip_reader_init_cfile , _mz_zip_reader_extract_to_mem , _mz_zip_reader_init_file_v2 , _mz_zip_reader_extract_to_mem_no_alloc , _mz_zip_reader_init_mem , _mz_zip_reader_extract_iter_read , _mz_zip_reader_init , _mz_zip_reader_locate_file , _mz_zip_reader_extract_iter_free , _mz_zip_reader_extract_file_to_file , _mz_zip_reader_extract_file_to_mem , _mz_zip_reader_is_file_supported , _mz_zip_reader_extract_file_to_cfile , _mz_zip_writer_add_from_zip_reader , _mz_zip_reader_end , _mz_zip_read_archive_data , _mz_zip_reader_extract_to_file , _mz_zip_reader_extract_to_callback )
  "_realloc", referenced from:
      _miniz_def_realloc_func in miniz-444461.o
      _tdefl_output_buffer_putter in miniz-444461.o
      _tdefl_write_image_to_png_file_in_memory_ex in miniz-444461.o
      _tinfl_decompress_mem_to_heap in miniz-444461.o
      _zip_str_file_path in zip-fff898.o
     (maybe you meant: _miniz_def_realloc_func)
  "_remove", referenced from:
      _mz_zip_add_mem_to_archive_file_in_place_v2 in miniz-444461.o
  "_stat$INODE64", referenced from:
      _mz_zip_writer_add_file in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_add_mem_to_archive_file_in_place_v2 in miniz-444461.o
      _zip_set_permissions in zip-fff898.o
      _zip_file_exists in zip-fff898.o
      _zip_unzip in zip-fff898.o
  "_strcpy", referenced from:
      _zip_str_file_path in zip-fff898.o
  "_strlen", referenced from:
      _mz_zip_reader_locate_file_v2 in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_validate_file in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_writer_add_mem_ex_v2 in miniz-444461.o
      _mz_zip_writer_add_cfile in miniz-444461.o
      _zip_str_file_path in zip-fff898.o
  "_strrchr", referenced from:
      _zip_str_file_path in zip-fff898.o
  "_time", referenced from:
      _mz_zip_writer_add_mem_ex_v2 in miniz-444461.o
  "_utime", referenced from:
      _mz_zip_reader_extract_to_file in miniz-444461.o
  "_utimes", referenced from:
      _zip_set_mtime in zip-fff898.o
      _zip_unzip in zip-fff898.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang-4.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Makevars:9: tools/cmdzip] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘zip’
* removing ‘/Users/hephaeschuen/anaconda3/lib/R/library/zip’
* restoring previous ‘/Users/hephaeschuen/anaconda3/lib/R/library/zip’
```

I think I need some serious clarifications about what has happened:
 1. Why is the package successfully installed and functional in Rstudio, but not installed at all at the terminal level?
 2. What does the above error message suggest?
 3. How should "zip" be installed successfully?

Comment: Hi Hephaes Does this link help you?   https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200554786-Problem-Installing-Packages

Comment: @pnorton, I checked the link but I can't see the answer to the issues. I have updated the situations with more information, btw.

Comment: Hi Hephaes. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Are you able to install packages in R?

Comment: Yes. No problem at all installing it in Rstudio console, the problems only arise when I install it in terminal.

Comment: "If you're having issues, we recommend trying to --> install packages in R (outside of RStudio) and see if you're able to do that.<-- If not, please check the possible solutions below." Ref 3 paragraph https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200554786-Problem-Installing-Packages